# Laravel and remote mount points (sshfs)

Tags: php, linux, laravel, laravel-5, mount

I've mounted a drive with sshfs to use with my web app, specifically for a directory listing part of my site. (i.e listing all directories / files in a folder)

As I don't store my files where my laravel installation is, I decided to use sshfs to mount my drive where laravel scans the dir.

An ls on the mounted directory shows all my files where they're suppose to be, mounted correctly.

However with laravel it throws the error "Links are not supported, encountered link at //initrd.img"

Any input would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: sshfs does not support hard links

Comment: @Michael , are there any alternatives? Thanks.

Comment: Another issue is, if you mount as `user`, PHP will not be able to access it, since it is run as a different user (`apache` or `httpd`).

Answer (score 1):

As per replies, Laravel doesn't support soft links so I ended up using NFS which worked perfectly. If anyone's interested on setting up NFS it's really easy: http://www.tecmint.com/how-to-setup-nfs-server-in-linux/

Thanks!